# Ruby On Rails Heroku db:migrate Aborted!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've pushed my app to Heroku and now am trying to run '$ heroku rake db:migrate'. I get this error:

PGError: ERROR:  relation "inventories" does not exist
: SELECT     "inventories".* FROM       "inventories"

On my local machine everything works great. The local is using SQLite 3. Also, previous versions of the app worked just fine -- the previous versions did include the inventories model. Now, I've read ( almost ) every post on stackoverflow and on the web about this issue, but I still cannot find a way around it. Does anybody have any advice on getting this to work?

Ruby 1.9.2
ROR 3

UPDATE..
Here is the source to the migration that creates the inventories table:

```
class CreateInventories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :inventories do |t|
      t.decimal :initial_amount, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
      t.decimal :remaining_amount, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
      t.string :unit
      t.decimal :cost, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
      t.integer :type_id
      t.integer :brand_id
      t.integer :blend_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.boolean :in

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :inventories
  end
end
```

Comment: Your table name is for sure "inventories" and not "inventory?"

Comment: Yep, here it is in the schema: create_table "inventories", :force => true do |t|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: I finally figured out the issue. I had this method in my user model:

```
def self.search( id )
  @inventory = Inventory.where(:primary_user [id])
  @cups = Cup.where(:user_id [id])

  @inventory + @cups
end
```

For some reason, that caused errors. I updated it to use `@user.inventories` and `@user.cups` instead. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the table does not exist remotely. See this:
http://docs.heroku.com/database#common-issues-migrating-to-postgresql

I would expect a previous db:migrate to have created the table, unless database changes have occurred outside of the rake db task. I find that it's rather easy to get this out of sync. You can run specific migrations by specifying the migration method desired (up or down) and the timestamp of the migration to be executed. An example:

```
heroku rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20101108092153
```

This runs the migration generated on 11/8/2010 at 9:21:53 AM. You can browse your migrations in the db/ folder to find the migration that contains the missing table.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to use the versions. I ran that line on a few different versions, but still got the same error. I pasted the error in a comment above. I read the article you referenced and tried running ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
 to see if the table had been created. I got an error saying it was an invalid command. Any ideas on how to debug this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this the first time you've migrated on Heroku? If so, are you using Postgres locally?

Comment: No and yes. I had the app on Heroku but destroyed it and tried from scratch. I got the same error when the app had been migrated before and I got the error on the brand new app. I am using sqlite 3 locally.

Comment: Could you add the source of the failing migration to the question?

Comment: Added the source for the migration i think is failing ( its the on that creates the inventories table )

Comment: There's really nothing in that migration that should be causing the select statement as seen in your trace file. Assuming that you have indeed tried running this specific migration, I suspect that the Postgres support in ActiveRecord 3 is not stellar.

Comment: FYI: `heroku rake:db:migrate:up` should be `heroku rake db:migrate:up`.  You need to lose the first colon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the Inventory model in your migration? Maybe you have an error in your migration, for example you edited the migration file after you migrated your local database?

In any case, running `rake --trace db:migrate` should show you the whole error message, together with stack trace - you will find the problematic line of code.

UPDATE:

In your stack trace (link is in the comment) there is one suspicious line:

```
...0-d4e1268c8981/mnt/config/environment.rb:5
```

What code is there?

Comment: Here is what the trace looks like: http://pastie.org/private/keoyrgixjf6sdv7gy8tfqa . Unfortuanatly, I don't see that it gives me a line or even a specific file where the error is.

Comment: What is in the 5th line of your config/environment.rb ?

Comment: FIP::Application.initialize!  This app was based off another app I had been working on. Seems like this may need to be updated. I'll try updating and let you know.

Comment: You may also try to comment out this line for the time of migration. Maybe this will fix the problem?