# Heroku db:migrate error, removed index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

New to rails and having some Heroku troubles. I created a table and with it an index. I needed to change a field name, and naturally the index goes with. So I created three migrations, one to remove the field, the next to remove the index, and the last to add both. My computer has no issues handling this migration, but Heroku fails.

I have tried merging migrations #1 and #2 into one migration, but had no luck with that.

```
Index name 'index_updateresults_on_env_id_and_created_at' on table 'updateresults' does not exist/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:825:in `index_name_for_remove'
```

Edit: 
May as well add my migrations.

```
class CreateUpdateresults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :updateresults do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :env_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :updateresults, [:env_id, :created_at]
  end
end

class RemoveEnvIdFromUpdateresults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :updateresults, :env_id, :string
    remove_index :updateresults, [:env_id, :created_at]
  end
end

class AddEnvNameToUpdateresults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :updateresults, :env_name, :string
    add_index :updateresults, [:env_name, :created_at]
  end
end
```

**Edit 2**

I'm at a loss. It seems as though in Postgre, removing a field also removes any indexes on that field. This may not happen in SqlLite, hence why my local environment works but Heroku breaks (just a guess). I've tried deleting the migration that removes the index to hopefully avoid this issue, I've committed the change, and pushed it to Heroku. Yet I'm still getting the same error, and when I clone the repo the migration still exists. Maybe this is something Git related and less Rails related.

Comment: The index does not exist on Heroku, did you ever run the migration that added it on Heroku? Comment the index removing code and upload to Heroku then run the migrations.

Comment: I should really look into swapping away from SqlLite in development, I think that's going to be a tonight project. Anyway, I have five migrations total. Create env, create updateresults (env_id and index for env_id), remove env_id, remove index for env_id, add env_name and index for env_name.

Answer (score 0):

Found a lot of information [at this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256926/ruby-on-rails-heroku-dbmigrate-aborted?rq=1). I ended up being right in that it was git related. Completely unsure why my commits that were deleting the file, weren't taking place on Heroku. I ultimately did a git rm commitname, then heroku push -f to my repository. It finally took at this point.